# Django HttpResponse with application/zip type corrupt

Tags: python, django

When I log the request in my frontend, I see characters like this:

```
PKS/L'�I�rrQUsers/my/local/dev_env/django_app/webapp/webapp/csvs/mailMagaOutput.csv会員id,e-mail,お名前(姓),お名前(名),購入回数
```

And the response logs the rest of the CSV files I am trying to log as the way they should look... Does this mean that I am not properly encrypting them?

The response I am sending (from Django):

```
zipped_file = zipfile.ZipFile("csvOutput.zip", 'w')
zipped_file.write(sms_file_path)
zipped_file.write(mail_maga_file_path)
zipped_file.close()

response_file = open('csvOutput.zip', 'rb')
response = HttpResponse(response_file, content_type="application/zip")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=csvOutput.zip"'
```

If I try to unzip the file that python generates on the server, it works just fine. When I try to unzip it locally, I am getting:

```
 tar: Too-small extra data: Need at least 4 bytes, but only found 3 bytes
```

**Note:** the zip file contains two CSV files, those CSV files, are in two different Japanese encodings, `shift_jis` and `shiftjisx0213`

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the file's name? Is there some kind of encoding I should be running on the file?? Been stuck on this forever ><

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the full path in the zipfile can you just zip the CSV files only?

**EX:**

```
import os
import zipfile

zipped_file = zipfile.ZipFile("csvOutput.zip", 'w')
os.chdir("/path/to/ CSV file path ")

zipped_file.write('mail_maga_file.csv')
zipped_file.write('sms_file.csv')
zipped_file.close()
```

Comment: interesting, let me give it a shot.

Comment: Yeah, even moving to that directory, writing to the zip file, and then moving back to open the zip file I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 14: invalid start byte

Comment: I am working around by just chaining the CSV file downloads one at a time for now :/ it's just a script to help a coworker with productivity anyway. I really appreciate your help but have to run home now. I will check again tomorrow if you want to keep working on it haha but no worries. Appreciate all your help!